# java: performing get-set operations efficiently in hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, time-complexity

I am trying to implement the following functions in my program using hashmap.

- get - dictGet() with 2 arguments
- getBit - dictGet() with 3 arguments
- set - dictSet() with 2 arguments
- setBit - dictSet() with 3 arguments

Here is the code.

```
static HashMap<String, Object> hashmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public static String dictGet(String key){
    String val = (String) hashmap.get(key);
    return val;
}

public static int dictGet(String key, int pos){ 
    String val = (String) hashmap.get(key);
    byte[] bytes = val.getBytes(); 
    byte byt = bytes[pos /8];
    System.out.println("Byte : "+byt); 
    return (byt >> (pos % 8) ) & 1;

}
public static void dictSet(String key, String val){
    hashmap.put(key, val);
}
public static void dictSet(String key, int pos, byte bitval){
    String val = (String) hashmap.get(key);
    byte[] bytes = val.getBytes();
    byte byt = bytes[pos /8];

    if(bitval == 1){
        bytes[pos /8] = (byte) (bytes[pos /8]| (1 << (pos % 8)));
    }
    else if(bitval == 0){
        bytes[pos /8] = (byte) (bytes[pos /8] & ~(1 << (pos % 8)));
    }

    hashmap.put(key, new String(bytes));
}
```

I want to achieve O(1) complexity for each of these functions. But currently getBit() and setBit() functions are taking O(n) time complexity. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where is getBit and setBit method?

Comment: getBit is dictGet() with 3 arguments and setBit is dictSet() with 3 arguments.@SMA